# Unable to reproduce iOS App Review team Crash. Unity app with Vuforia

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash

We have submitted two apps recently (one new app, and one which was an update of an already published app) and got the two rejected by the iOS app review team for the following reason:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance
> Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network during our review.

Before submitting the apps we extensively tested them with testflight on 4 different devices and iOS versions and experienced no crash at all.
We are unable to reproduce the crash the iOS app review team experience

Our dev environment is the same for the two apps, may be this is the cause of the crash :
Unity 2017.2.1f1 with Vuforia (this is an augmented reality app), XCode 9.2 (latest version)

Hereafter you will find the crashlog for the new app,( the updated app had an identical crashlog...), they are very similar:

The two crashlogs are very similar:

```
{"app_name":"ournewappname","timestamp":"2018-03-01 17:04:56.02 -0800","app_version":"1.0.1","slice_uuid":"af7e5c57-c2bc-3c91-8e1e-559acfccdb7f","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"fr.ourcompany.ournewappname","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)","incident_id":"002164F5-FD42-4A49-BF58-E8C1CB773010","name":"ournewappname"}

Incident Identifier: 002164F5-FD42-4A49-BF58-E8C1CB773010
CrashReporter Key:   6fa54cb83ccb006df1d056599e75f6797f1ac664
Hardware Model:      iPad5,1
Device Model:        J96AP
Process:             ournewappname [4216]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/752BA8CA-A7AE-4823-976E-1D5DEBD34B2E/ournewappname.app/ournewappname
Identifier:          fr.ourcompany.ournewappname
Version:             1 (1.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]
Coalition:           fr.ourcompany.ournewappname [1066]


Date/Time:           2018-03-01 17:04:55.8059 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-03-01 17:04:54.7575 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    n/a
UDID:                a728c3d680bc84aaaddc473d254d3c02a764955f
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000088
VM Region Info: 0x88 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4301520760
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000100640000-0000000100644000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...ealtwrarcard]

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
Timestamp               Thread     Type        Activity             PID
2018-03-01 17:04:54.8314 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 AssertionServices: BKSWorkspace created.
2018-03-01 17:04:54.9677 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 AccessibilitySettingsLoader: Loading settings loader: (system: 0)
2018-03-01 17:04:54.9790 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 AccessibilitySettingsLoader: AXSettingsLoader told to start
2018-03-01 17:04:54.9967 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIAccessibility: Starting accessibility server
2018-03-01 17:04:55.1193 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIAccessibility: Started AXRuntime server: 0
2018-03-01 17:04:55.1239 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIAccessibility: (null): Loading synchronously
2018-03-01 17:04:55.1262 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIAccessibility: Main bundle finished loading: load type: 0 - is system app server: 0 (<UIApplication: 0x113d0adb0>)
2018-03-01 17:04:55.2735 -0800  0xfd3c 1024 0x0 4216 FrontBoardServices: [FBSScene] [fr.ourcompany.ournewappname] Created client agent: <UIApplicationSceneClientAgent: 0x1c401d120>
2018-03-01 17:04:55.2742 -0800  0xfd3c 1024 0x0 4216 FrontBoardServices: [FBSScene] [fr.ourcompany.ournewappname - AirPlay] Created client agent: <UIApplicationSceneClientAgent: 0x1c001d3f0>
2018-03-01 17:04:55.7238 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIKit: View did appear: <SplashScreenController: 0x113d6d690> 1
2018-03-01 17:04:55.7253 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIAccessibility: Did post notification. notification:  (1001) error:0 data:(null)
2018-03-01 17:04:55.7334 -0800  0xfd29 1024 0x0 4216 UIAccessibility: Did post notification. notification:  (4002) error:0 data:{
    controllerClass = SplashScreenController;
    event = ViewDidAppear;
}

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ournewappname                   0x0000000100b3e9d8 0x100640000 + 5237208
1   ournewappname                   0x000000010065339c 0x100640000 + 78748
2   ournewappname                   0x0000000100653740 0x100640000 + 79680
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c513c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20 (CFNotificationCenter.c:661)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c46dc _CFXRegistrationPost + 420 (CFNotificationCenter.c:163)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c4440 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1060)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181241e24 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408 (CFXNotificationRegistrar.m:163)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810fad60 _CFXNotificationPost + 380 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1057)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181b27348 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68 (NSNotification.m:543)
9   UIKit                           0x000000018ad28a20 +[UIScreen _FBSDisplayConfigurationConnected:andNotify:] + 280 (UIScreen.m:599)
10  UIKit                           0x000000018aa51060 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 292 (UIApplication.m:3094)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ae66dbc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:41)
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001838f61f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364 (FBSSceneImpl.m:460)
13  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001838feaf8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224 (FBSWorkspace.m:606)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb2a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bba200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288 (queue.c:3025)
16  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018392a7f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36 (FBSSerialQueue.m:164)
17  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018392a49c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404 (FBSSerialQueue.m:196)
18  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018392aa38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:232)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811db77c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811db6fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811daf84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811d8b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810f8c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
24  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182fa4f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
25  UIKit                           0x000000018a8515c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
26  ournewappname                   0x0000000100645980 0x100640000 + 22912
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180c1856c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.frontboardservices.workspace.client
Thread 3:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810f3d6c CFDataGetBytePtr + 88 (CFInternal.h:714)
1   Foundation                      0x0000000181b3296c bytesInEncoding + 200 (NSStringEncodings.m:155)
2   Foundation                      0x0000000181b3296c bytesInEncoding + 200 (NSStringEncodings.m:155)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181104f6c -[__NSCFString UTF8String] + 80 (CFObject.m:228)
4   BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703ee8 BSSerializeStringToXPCDictionaryWithKey + 44 (BSXPCSerialization.m:171)
5   BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703ce8 BSSerializeBSXPCEncodableObjectToXPCDictionary + 52 (BSXPCSerialization.m:86)
6   BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703ca4 BSCreateSerializedBSXPCEncodableObject + 56 (BSXPCSerialization.m:51)
7   BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703d88 BSSerializeBSXPCEncodableObjectToXPCDictionaryWithKey + 40 (BSXPCSerialization.m:59)
8   FrontBoardServices              0x00000001838f929c -[FBSWorkspaceSceneClientSettingsChangedEvent encodeWithXPCDictionary:] + 84 (FBSWorkspaceSceneClientSettingsChangedEvent.m:52)
9   BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703ce8 BSSerializeBSXPCEncodableObjectToXPCDictionary + 52 (BSXPCSerialization.m:86)
10  BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703ca4 BSCreateSerializedBSXPCEncodableObject + 56 (BSXPCSerialization.m:51)
11  BaseBoard                       0x0000000183703d88 BSSerializeBSXPCEncodableObjectToXPCDictionaryWithKey + 40 (BSXPCSerialization.m:59)
12  BaseBoard                       0x0000000183720a30 +[BSXPCMessage messageWithPacker:] + 96 (BSXPCMessage.m:33)
13  BaseBoard                       0x000000018371db08 -[BSBaseXPCClient _sendMessage:withReplyHandler:waitForReply:waitDuration:] + 132 (BSBaseXPCClient.m:187)
14  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183918710 -[FBSWorkspaceClient _queue_sendMessage:withEvent:withResponseEvent:ofType:] + 144 (FBSWorkspaceClient.m:300)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb2a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb2a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bbc96c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528 (inline_internal.h:2500)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bbd2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340 (queue.c:5302)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bbdd20 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404 (queue.c:5920)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bc603c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644 (source.c:2529)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5af1c _pthread_wqthread + 932 (pthread.c:2207)
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d27568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d273e0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811db108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811d8cd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810f8c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181b2d594 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181b4c9ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b3bb7a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:437)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181c2f0f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c2b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  GC Finalizer
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d480f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ece4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   ournewappname                   0x00000001012e86a8 0x100640000 + 13272744
3   ournewappname                   0x00000001012cd658 0x100640000 + 13162072
4   ournewappname                   0x00000001012e5400 0x100640000 + 13259776
5   ournewappname                   0x00000001012e8df0 0x100640000 + 13274608
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c2b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  BatchDeleteObjects
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d275a4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb4f04 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24 (lock.c:134)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb58b4 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 140 (semaphore.c:143)
3   ournewappname                   0x0000000100d546b8 0x100640000 + 7423672
4   ournewappname                   0x0000000100cd40dc 0x100640000 + 6897884
5   ournewappname                   0x0000000100d53c8c 0x100640000 + 7421068
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c2b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  AsyncReadManager
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d275a4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb4f04 _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24 (lock.c:134)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180bb58b4 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 140 (semaphore.c:143)
3   ournewappname                   0x0000000100c3c530 0x100640000 + 6276400
4   ournewappname                   0x0000000100c3c074 0x100640000 + 6275188
5   ournewappname                   0x0000000100d53c8c 0x100640000 + 7421068
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c2b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5c180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e5ab74 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000048   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000101f8b03c
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000403
    x8: 0x0000000101f8fa40   x9: 0x0000000000000001  x10: 0x0000000101f8ad60  x11: 0x0000000113d15730
   x12: 0x0000000101f8adb8  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000113e01680  x15: 0x016b5c01016b5cc0
   x16: 0x0000000180e51c60  x17: 0x0000000181b31d38  x18: 0xfffffff01210d25c  x19: 0x0000000000000002
   x20: 0x000000016f7bdc38  x21: 0x0000000101f8a000  x22: 0x0000000000000002  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000002  x25: 0x000000016f7bdc38  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x00000001b2373650
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f7bdb60   lr: 0x0000000100b3e9d8
    sp: 0x000000016f7bd9f0   pc: 0x0000000100b3e9d8 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

As we could not reproduce the crash its difficult to fix.
In this crashlog there is something about SplashScreenController, so just in case we removed the splashscreen, and also changed Unity Version to 2017.3.1 and resubmitted the app...

Any help would really be appreciated, perhaps we are missing some useful information in the crash log?

Comment: the second submission with no splashscreen and unity 2017.3.1 was rejected to for the same reason. but with a different crash log. something about : Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: fr.ourCompanyName.ourProjectName exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds |  | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 25.530 (user 25.530, system 0.000), 79% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time

Comment: As the last log seems to have something to do with loading time that took to long and the app being killed by the system, we added asynchronous loading and reduced texture size to improve load time.

Comment: The app was rejected one more time, for the same reason, and now apple did not give us a CrashLog. We are really stuck :(  And still no clear answer from apple.

Comment: Next we will try to use an older version of Unity / Vuforia / Xcode. Hope it will work...

Comment: I received the same rejection from Apple last night for an update to my app built with 2017.30f3 and Xcode 9.2. I don't use Vuforia, so that doesn't appear to be the issue. I suspected that maybe the Unity IAP plugin was the culprit, although I haven't seen anyone else with this issue mention that they're using that. I believe my last several updates have been submitted with the same Unity and Xcode versions, so it seems like they wouldn't be at fault. I'll post an update if I learn anything else.

Comment: I also meant to mention that I'm using CoreBluetooth, which is another thing that I suspected could be the culprit.

Comment: I believe I'm able to reproduce the crash locally now. I've been testing on an iPhone X and iPhone 7 connected to wifi. I haven't been able to repro on the iPhone X, but I found that if I turn wifi off on the iPhone 7, about 30% of the time the app crashes on startup due to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in a Unity background worker, and UnityWebRequestProto.h is mentioned in the assembly stack snapshot in Xcode. I don't make any web requests within my Unity code, so this appears to be due to Unity instrumentation, and I will look at removing the IAP plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today an App review team guy finally examined our case and validated our app although it was marked as rejected before.

The app got rejected 5 times in a row, with always the same message and no crash logs the last two times.

We contacted the app review team 4 days ago to appeal an app rejection with this form :https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal

I think Apple test procedure relies heavily on automatic testing and in some cases this is not reliable, their "bot" reject our app although its working perfectly.

What Apple seems to ignore, is that we spent sleepless nights doing everything possible to find a solution so that our client had his application on time...

I wish goodluck to everyone with this problem and i can only advice you to enter in contact with apple by all means  to have a person who will look at your app.

Answer (score 6):

We were running into the same issue (same Exception and app store rejection). We came across this Unity bug that seemed to be the culprit.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-11-build-crashes-on-remotear-unityupdatedisplaylist-when-launching-app-from-url-with-airplay-connected

There was a bug that caused this crash when users were streaming their device screen (AirPlay etc). I assume testers sometimes use AirPlay, causing the crash, while developers saw nothing wrong.

Luckily this bug has been corrected in Unity and has been backported to several Unity patch versions:

Fixed in:
**2018.1.0b1**

Backported to:
**2017.3.0p2
2017.2.1p2
2017.1.3p1**

After updating from 2017.2.1 to 2017.2.1p2, our app was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

We had an AR app rejected for the same reasons last Friday. We're using Unity 2017.3.0f3 with native Vuforia integration and Xcode 9.2; we're also using Native Share.

The crash log we received from Apple looks pretty much the same as yours @Jeff; same exception type and methods shown on the crashed thread.

I'll try your approach of downgrading to a different version of Unity and will share my results.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000088
VM Region Info: 0x88 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4377919352
  REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
  UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
  __TEXT                 0000000104f1c000-0000000104f20000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  .../OurApp]

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

and

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   OurApp                      0x0000000105463334 0x104f1c000 + 5534516
1   OurApp                      0x0000000104f2f130 0x104f1c000 + 78128
2   OurApp                      0x0000000104f2f4d4 0x104f1c000 + 79060
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184bd113c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20 (CFNotificationCenter.c:661)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184bd06dc _CFXRegistrationPost + 420 (CFNotificationCenter.c:163)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184bd0440 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1060)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184c4de24 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1408 (CFXNotificationRegistrar.m:163)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b06d60 _CFXNotificationPost + 380 (CFNotificationCenter.c:1057)
8   Foundation                      0x0000000185533348 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68 (NSNotification.m:543)
9   UIKit                           0x000000018e734a20 +[UIScreen _FBSDisplayConfigurationConnected:andNotify:] + 280 (UIScreen.m:599)
10  UIKit                           0x000000018e45d060 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 292 (UIApplication.m:3094)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018e872dbc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] +                     364 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:41)
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001873021f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364 (FBSSceneImpl.m:460)
13  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018730aaf8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224 (FBSWorkspace.m:606)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001845bea14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001845c6200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288 (queue.c:3025)
16  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001873367f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36 (FBSSerialQueue.m:164)
17  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018733649c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404 (FBSSerialQueue.m:196)
18  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000187336a38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:232)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184be777c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184be76fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184be6f84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184be4b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184b04c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
24  GraphicsServices                0x00000001869b0f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
25  UIKit                           0x000000018e25d5c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
26  OurApp                      0x0000000104f21880 0x104f1c000 + 22656
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018462456c start + 4
```

Comment: Our app just got rejected one more time with XCode 9.0 instead of Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Did you succeed with the downgrading to a different version of Unity ?

Comment: My app is currently Under Review. For this build I used Unity 2017.1.2f1, Xcode 9.2, and the Vuforia Legacy Unity package; that was the setup used for the last app that got approved. As soon as I hear back from Apple, I'll share it here!

Answer (score 1):

Since last week, we also suffered from rejected our applications for the similar reason.
Then, I looked at the post of @HidingGlass and applied the Unity's patch.
As a result, our applications passed Apple's review.

I'll share the result.

- Reject : ver.2017.2.1f1
- Accept : ver.2017.2.1p2

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, we are having the exact same issue over here. We have been sending Apple builds to review before, and they all worked on their devices(only rejected for some minor issues), up until a couple days ago. They have rejected two of our builds due to this 'crash', despite the fact they are working fine on our test devices.

What is strange about this, is that they had the same thing to say about both our submissions:

"Your app crashed on iPad or iPhone running iOS 11.2.5 connected to an IPv6 network during our review."

Not only that, but the crash logs provided by them also reflect the same issue as yours.

`Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000088
VM Region Info: 0x88 is not in any region.`

For now, we are about to send a previous build that was working in their review, and see what they have to say about it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing and its interesting to see we are not the only ones facing this problem. I begin to think the problem comes from Apple...
@RPGamer, did you use Vuforia Augmented reality to ?

Comment: Still no answer from apple. I feel i am stuck with a stupid bot. Its very frustrating for me and my customer who could not get their app on time for their event.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment on your question, I'm sporadically able to reproduce this crash locally by turning off wifi on my iPhone 7. After some more digging I found that someone had added this issue to the Unity issue tracker at the end of February, but it appears that the webpage for that issue was made inaccessible either today or yesterday.

The issue tracker webpage was originally accessible here:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unitywebrequest-ios-2017-dot-3-player-crashes-at-job-executeunitywebrequest-when-switching-to-airplane-mode

Google still has it cached here, though:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:TcQczK0adjMJ:https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/unitywebrequest-ios-2017-dot-3-player-crashes-at-job-executeunitywebrequest-when-switching-to-airplane-mode&num=1&hl=en&gl=us&strip=0&vwsrc=0

The webpage doesn't render correctly at the cached URL, but I was able to view it by viewing the source and saving it to an HTML file on my machine. Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

The stack trace in the issue matches what I see when I reproduce the issue locally. Interestingly, the comment on the issue mentions that this is causing apps that use Vuforia to crash. I don't use Vuforia, but apparently something else in my stack (probably the GVR SDK) is sending the web request that is leading to my crash.

Update 1:
Following the recommendation in the page's comment, I downgraded to Unity 2017.2.1f and found that the crash no longer occurs. So, I'll submit this build of my app and see what happens. As you have said that you're already using that version of Unity, maybe this is actually a different problem than what you're experiencing.

Update 2:
My app update was just approved by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Yes I am on Unity 2017.2.1f, i uninstalled our app, and did a proper install with testflight. then i enabled flight mode, launched the app and it worked as usual, could not reproduce the crash that seems to occurs at Apple Review Team.
I tryed to enable/disable flight mode multiple times while the app was running, and quit / launched the app in different conditions and it always worked, tested on 6 different devices with same procedure. i dont think there is any random crash.

Comment: my app still got reject, do you have any update Jeff

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we've been on Unity 5.6.3p4 for the last couple of app updates in January and were approved just fine, and very quickly (less than 1 day from submission to approval). A week ago, however, the app was in the state of 'In Review' for 3 days and then we got rejection due to the same crash issue as described here, while we didn't change Unity version and didn't add any new external frameworks - so, by reading all of the other replied here, I suspect that Apple must have recently changed something in their review test bot (like started using AirPlay), which triggered these issues because of a dormant Unity bug.

It's interesting that this issue is being actively discussed in Unity issues tracker and Unity engineer just posted a work-around in the DisplayManager.mm code, and also they just backported the fix to 5.6.5p3:
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-11-build-crashes-on-remotear-unityupdatedisplaylist-when-launching-app-from-url-with-airplay-connected?page=1#comments

As for us, we upgraded to 2017.1.3p2 and resubmitted, and got rejected again - but this time with a different crash report:

```
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.ourComany.ourApp exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds
```

and this seems like some brand new issue that's being discussed here since yesterday:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-crash-on-startup-unity-2017-1-3p2.521666/#post-3424784